# Android - listview with custom adapter fails when new items scrolled into view

Tags: android

Having a slight problem with a listview.  It works fine with one exception: when I scroll down past the bottom of the listview, I get a nullpointerexception. Using the debugger, I have verified that the arraylist is loaded in exactly the correct order and that the date labels are right where they should be. However, once I start scrolling to where a new item has to come into view, I get the error. I'm not sure why this is occurring, and only when the list is scrolled enough so that some elements pop off and others need to come into view.

```
 public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private static ArrayList<Object> searchArrayList;

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> results) {

  searchArrayList = results;
  mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 }

 public int getCount() {
  return searchArrayList.size();
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return searchArrayList.get(position);
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
 }

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object item = getItem(position);

    if(item instanceof Appointment) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        // It's a section title:
        return 1;
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    Object item = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null) 
    {
        // Create item view for first time
        if(item instanceof Appointment) 
        {   // inflate appointment list view item layout
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
        } 
        else 
        {   // inflate title section list view item layout
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item_header, null); 
        }
    }

    // Update list view item view according to type:
    if(item instanceof Appointment) 
    {
        Appointment a = (Appointment) item;

        ViewHolder holder;

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtAttendee = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attendee);
        holder.txtSummary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.summary);
        holder.txtStarts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.starts);
        holder.txtEnds = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ends);
        holder.txtCategories = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categories);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 16);

        holder.txtAttendee.setText(a.GetAttendee());  // exception here
        holder.txtSummary.setText(">" + a.GetSummary());
        String st = a.GetDTStart().toString();
        String en = a.GetDTEnd().toString();

        holder.txtStarts.setText(st.substring(0,16));
        holder.txtEnds.setText(en.substring(0,16)); 

        String cat = a.GetCategories();
        holder.txtCategories.setText(cat);

    } 
    else if(item instanceof String)
    {
        // Item is a section header string:
        String label = (String) item;
        // Retrieve label TextView from convertView... etc...
        HeaderHolder holder;

        holder = new HeaderHolder();

        holder.txtHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
        convertView.setClickable(false);
        convertView.setFocusable(false);

        holder.txtHeader.setText(" " + label);
    }

    return convertView;
}

 static class ViewHolder 
 {
     TextView txtAttendee;
     TextView txtSummary;
     TextView txtStarts;
     TextView txtEnds;
     TextView txtCategories;
 }

 static class HeaderHolder
 {
     TextView txtHeader;

 }
}
```

I get a nullpointerexception at "ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy" at line 2414.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to tell exactly where your code is failing. you quoted the exception point that lies in the Android code. we need to see the entire stack trace, specifically where it starts in your code, and the corresponding line in your code (the code fragment you posted doesn't have line numbers).

at least one problem is that you are mixing views in your implementation of `getView()`. in the case when `convertView` is not null, there's no connection between the type of `convertView` and the type of item. `convertView` could be a recycled version of either of the two views you inflate. it won't necessarily match up with the type of the item.

you then try to find particular views in `convertView`, which may or may not exist. voila, NPE.

if you are doing to mix views like this, you have to inflate a new one each time; you cannot use `convertView`.

if you want to use `convertView`, and you really have different types of things in a single list, you need to create an uber-view that is the merging of the views for each type. then you make one section or the other visible depending on the type of the item, and hide the other section.